# System.Diagnostic.Process is not returning the exception thrown from an application

Tags: c#

I'm using `SSMAforAccessConsole32.exe` for migrating Access DB to SQL DB. Since I need to call the `exe`. I have used `Process exeProcess = Process.Start(objPSI)` to start the process. When the `SSMAforAccessConsole32.exe` throws some exception it is not returning back the exception.

Need help in getting the exception thrown by the `exe`. Any help would be appreciated.

Please find code below.

```
ProcessStartInfo objPSI = new ProcessStartInfo();
objPSI.Arguments = "-s " + '"' + strDir + "AssessmentReportGenerationSample.xml" + '"' + " -c " + '"' + strDir + "ServersConnectionFileSample.xml" + '"' + " -v " + '"' + strDir + strVariableFile + '"';
//objPSI.Arguments = "-s " + '"' + strDir + "AssessmentReportGenerationSample.xml" + '"' + " -c " + '"' + strDir + "ServersConnectionFileSample.xml" + '"' + " -v " + '"' + strDir + "VariableValueFileSample.xml" + '"';
objPSI.FileName = strDIR1 + "SSMAforAccessConsole32.exe";
objPSI.CreateNoWindow = true;
objPSI.UseShellExecute = false;                    
objPSI.RedirectStandardError = true;
try
{
    using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(objPSI))
    {

        string error = exeProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        //  string strError = SSMAError.ExceptionResult.Propagate.ToString();                            
        //exeProcess.

        exeProcess.WaitForExit();                               
    }
}                 
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     // Log error.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it can't. Why would you think it would? As far as I know, the only way to get the exception would be to attach a debugger, which is a bit tricky, and pretty much impossible from .NET. If you need to communicate errors between processes, exceptions are most definitely not the proper way :) Also, `StandardError.ReadToEnd()` will be blocking, so there's no need for the `WaitForExit()`.

Comment: I'm developing a page.where based on the error I would show a message to the user,if the migration was successful or not.

Comment: So you're starting a process from a web server? That doesn't really sound like a good idea. In any case, don't use exceptions to propagate errors accross separate processes, that can't really be done. Instead, you could return the error messages through standard error, or the exit code, or you could just write this whole thing as a DLL rather than a separate EXE.

Comment: Let me explain you clearly.We have a requirement to migrate all the access db we have to sql server.So we are using the SSMAforAccessConsole32.exe" to migrate it.but sadly this tool takes only one accessDB at a time for migration.I'm just creating a wizard to migrate multiple access db files to SQL.In case if there is any issue in the migration process,it has to be communicated to the user.that's the primary reason why I w'd like to get back the error thrown from the application.

Comment: If the application throws an exception, you're not going to catch it, as simple as that. If there's a different way the application can propagate the error, use that. If not, you'll have to do this manually, I guess :) There's a few hacky options alongside too - you could read the error log messages using Event Viewer (all .NET unexpected exceptions go there), and you could add the exe as a reference and run it directly like that, in its own application domain. It's going to be quite tricky, though.

Comment: Rather than throwing an exception.I'm checking for exit code .if the process was successful the exit code will be 0.if it is 0 I assume it to be success.

Comment: if (exeProcess.ExitCode == 0)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Migrated Successfully");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Migration Failed");
                            }

Comment: Yeah, that should work well enough for an internal tool :)